# The gothicized metric and the Palatini formalism

Tags: homework-and-exercises, general-relativity, lagrangian-formalism, metric-tensor, variational-principle

In the Palatini formalism of GR, we had two results treating the metric $g_{\mu\nu}$ and the connection $\Gamma^\alpha_{\mu\nu}$ separately as dynamical variables, which are

- The vaccum field equations of GR.

And

- That the connection is necessarily the metric connection.

The later was obtained from varying the action w.r.t. the symmetric connection and we thus obtain:

$\nabla_\alpha (\sqrt{-g}g^{\mu\nu})=0$ , where we deduced the last result.

Now my question is how to obtain $\nabla_\alpha g_{\mu\nu}=0$ to be able to reach to such a result?

p.s. Ray D'Inverno called the tensor density $\sqrt{-g}g^{\mu\nu}$ a gothicized metric.

Answer (score 0):

The main idea answering this question was from [this](https://bit.ly/2yvCDcx) and here I'd like to answer in detail:

We only have this:  $\nabla_\lambda \sqrt{-g} g^{\mu\nu}=0$  ------(1

I will need some formulas which I will deduce firstly.

$\delta^\mu_\nu=g^{\mu\alpha} g_{\alpha \nu} \implies \nabla_\lambda \delta^\mu_\nu=g_{\alpha \nu}\nabla_\lambda g^{\mu\alpha} +g^{\mu\alpha} \nabla_\lambda g_{\alpha \nu}$

$\implies g_{\alpha \nu}\nabla_\lambda g^{\mu\alpha} =-g^{\mu\alpha} \nabla_\lambda g_{\alpha \nu}$

$\implies \nabla_\lambda g^{\mu\beta}=-g^{\mu \alpha} g^{\beta\nu}\nabla_\lambda g_{\alpha \nu}$       -------(2

We take as a priliminary (From the calculus of matrices) $\partial_\lambda \sqrt{-g}=\frac{1}{2}\sqrt{-g}g^{\mu\nu}\partial_\lambda g_{\mu\nu}$------(3

Now the tricks begin:

$\nabla_\lambda \sqrt{-g}=\partial_\lambda \sqrt{-g}- \Gamma^\zeta_{\zeta\lambda} \sqrt{-g}$ $~~~~~~~~~~as$ $\sqrt{-g}$ is a scalar density of weight +1.

$~~~~~~~~~~~~~= \frac{1}{2}\sqrt{-g}g^{\mu\nu}\partial_\lambda g_{\mu\nu}- \Gamma^\zeta_{\zeta\lambda} \sqrt{-g}$ $~~~~~~~~~$Using (3

$~~~~~~~~~~~~=\frac{1}{2}\sqrt{-g}g^{\mu\nu}\partial_\lambda g_{\mu\nu}-\sqrt{-g}g^{\mu\nu} \left(\frac{1}{2}\Gamma^\zeta_{\mu\lambda}g_{\zeta\nu}+\frac{1}{2}\Gamma^\zeta_{\nu\lambda}g_{\mu\zeta}\right)$

$~~~~~~~~~~~~=\frac{1}{2}\sqrt{-g}g^{\mu\nu}\nabla_\lambda g_{\mu\nu}$------(4

Now,

$\nabla_\lambda (\sqrt{-g}g^{\alpha\beta})=\sqrt{-g}\nabla_{\lambda}g^{\alpha\beta}+g^{\alpha\beta}\nabla_\lambda\sqrt{-g}$

Now use (1 and (3 to obtain:

$\nabla_\lambda (\sqrt{-g}g^{\alpha\beta})=-\sqrt{-g}g^{ \alpha\mu} g^{\beta\nu}\nabla_\lambda g_{\mu \nu}+\frac{1}{2}\sqrt{-g}g^{\alpha\beta}g^{\mu\nu}\nabla_\lambda g_{\mu\nu}$

$~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~=\sqrt{-g}\left(-g^{ \alpha\mu} g^{\beta\nu}+\frac{1}{2}g^{\alpha\beta}g^{\mu\nu}\right)\nabla_\lambda g_{\mu\nu}$

$~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~=0$

Contracting with $g_{\alpha\beta}$ we get

$g^{\mu\nu}\nabla_\lambda g_{\mu\nu}=0$------(5

Now here another trick:

$4 \nabla_\lambda \sqrt{-g}=\nabla_\lambda (g_{\mu\nu}g^{\mu\nu}\sqrt{-g})$

$~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~=g_{\mu\nu}\nabla_\lambda (g^{\mu\nu}\sqrt{-g}) + \sqrt{-g} (g^{\mu\nu} \nabla_\lambda g_{\mu\nu})$

Now using (1 and (5 we get:

$\nabla_\lambda \sqrt{-g}=0$

And from this using leibniz in (1 we can get easily: $\nabla_\lambda g^{\mu\nu}=0$ and hence using a simple calculation we get $\nabla_\lambda g_{\mu\nu}=0$. And the results of the Palatini formalism then follows easily.